# What made Alex change her mind in Quantico S01E09?

Tags: plot-explanation, quantico

I was wondering after watching [*Quantico* S01E09 ("Guilty")](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4724486/) why Alex pleaded guilty.

I can understand making her go to jail as if she was the culprit so the real terrorists think they are safe.  That makes sense.  But why does she plead guilty and not innocent?

Alex was pleading innocence ever since she was framed and even had an interview broadcast through the dark web.  Pleading guilty now makes no sense at all.  She could plead innocent and allow a rigged trial to convict her.